# DotNetNuke (dnn) - error on creating pages using version 5.6.3

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have installed DNN version 5.6.3 according to install instructions.

- create new folder and copy downloaded content in
- set permission for asp user and network service to full permissions on this folder
- created a new db in sql server with a login for it as dbo
- set the folder containing the site as an application in iis
- amended the web.config file to have the correct db connection information in two places

Firstly I tried to install it with the typical settings but this never went any further than updating db (stayed on this for hours).

Therefore I installed it with the auto settings and this went through successfully as I can see.

Now on my new portal I can log in successfully and change my password on the host and admin user but I cannot do anything else, like creating new pages etc.

The error I am getting is this:

```
Method: System.Net.WebPermission.IsSubsetOf
StackTrace: 
Message: System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenId, Version=2.4.2.8248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies.
Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) 
---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenId, Version=2.4.2.8248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) 
---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenId, Version=2.4.2.8248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) File name: 'DotNetOpenId, Version=2.4.2.8248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' 
---> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot subset Regex. Only support if both patterns are identical. at 
System.Net.WebPermission.IsSubsetOf(IPermission target) at 
System.Security.PermissionSet.IsSubsetOfHelper(PermissionSet target, IsSubsetOfType type, IPermission& firstPermThatFailed, Boolean ignoreNonCas) at 
System.Security.PermissionSet.IsSubsetOf(PermissionSet target) at 
System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) at 
System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean checkExecutionPermission) at 
System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) at 
System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) at 
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) at 
System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) at 
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) at 
System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.LoadAssembly(String assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) at 
...
```

I had this (a previous version of dnn) installed on the same sever for a different client a couple years back and it worked fine, but I can't seem to make it work this time. I compared all the settings and nothing is different.

Has anyone got any experience with this version and an idea how I could progress?

From what I have found Googling, it sounds like it could be a permissioning problem on the server, but not sure where to start since I've given the NETWORKUSER full access to the directory already.  Other suggestions seem to point towards .net 3.5 not being available to the website but I already have the framework installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the OpenID Authentication provider? You might need to delete that, or remove any reference to it from the web.config file.

You should also be sure, when you unzip the package for DNN, that Windows isn't blocking any of the files in the ZIP file. Right click on the ZIP file, and choose properties. If you see an "unblock" option do that, then extract the contents and try your installation again.

Comment: I installed only the default components, which I guess includes OpenID. I removed the DLL and uninstalled it from the control panel, but I am still getting exceptions when I try to create new pages. My host server is 2003 R2 and I can't see any 'Unblock' option in the security tab.

Comment: I would double check if it is still defined in the web.config file to see if that is causing the problem